# How many rare events for predictive modeling

Tags: predictive-models, sample-size, rare-events

In a binary classification problem, in the training data set, how many rare events should i have. I know that is difficult to say e.g. 100 but at least what factors should i take into accoun to determine the number of rare events?

Comment: THis isn't really enough information for an answer, can you tell us more? What covariables, and more or less how many, do you intend to use?

Comment: Hello,Yoy Mean how many input variables i have? lets us say that we have 20 input variables some of the m categorical (nominal and ordinal) and some interval. Does this help?